# Probability in Sets

Tags: probability

Let be two lists $l_1 = [1,\cdots,n]$ and $l_2 = [randint(1,n)_1,\cdots,randint(1,n)_m]$ where $randint(1,n)_i\neq randint(1,n)_j \,\,\, \forall i\neq j$ and $n>m$. How I will be able to found the number of elements $x\in l_1$, to select, such that the probability of $x \in l_2$ is $1/2$?. I'm trying using the birthday paradox but I cann't get.

$randint(x,y)$ pick a random number between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

The birthday paradox doesn't apply, because you are not looking for matches between any pair of elements.  Each element you select out of $l_1$ has $\frac mn$ chance of being in $l_2$ and these chances are independent.  If you select $k$ elements, the chance that none of them match any element in $l_2$ is then $(1-\frac mn)^k$, which you want to be $\frac 12$
$$(1-\frac mn)^k=\frac 12\\k \log(1-\frac mn)=-\log 2\\k=\frac{-\log 2}{\log(1-\frac mn)}$$

Comment: This assumes replacement.  If you have to pick $k$ distinct elements from $l_1$ then it's a little more complicated.  But this gives a good estimate either way.

Comment: @Jared:  that is true.  You did the harder case.

Answer (score 1):

There are $m$ out of $n$ numbers in $l_2$ which means the probability of a random selection from 1-n being in $l_2$ is $\frac{m}{n}$ (e.g. if $n = 10$ and $m = 9$ and $l_2$ is just 1-9, then there is only a 1 in 10 chance I will be unlucky and pick 10 which is not in $l_2$).  Due to the pigeonhole principle, once you pick more than $n - m$ times, you are guaranteed to have at least one value from $l_2$.  So let's simply say we pick $x$ times and find the probability that *none* of those was in $l_2$ (and assume $x < n - m$):

\begin{align*}
x = 1:& p(x = 1, fail) = \frac{n - m}{n}\\
x = 2:& p(x = 2, fail) = p(x = 1, fail) \cdot \frac{n - m - 1}{n - 1} \\
x = 3:& p(x = 3, fail) = p(x = 2, fail) \cdot \frac{n - m - 2}{n - 2} \\
x = \zeta:& p(x = \zeta, fail) = \prod_0^{\zeta - 1} \frac{n - m - \zeta}{n - \zeta}, \zeta \leq n - m
\end{align*}

But that product just consists of some familiar factorials:

$$
p(x = \zeta, fail) = \frac{(n - m)!(n - \zeta)!}{(n - m - \zeta)!n!}
$$

This is permutations, not combinations, so it's not the binomial coefficient, although we can write it in terms of a binomial coefficient:

$$
(n\ P\ m) = \binom{n}{m}m!
$$

So we have:

$$
p(x = \zeta, fail) = \frac{\binom{n - m}{\zeta}\zeta!}{\binom{n}{\zeta}\zeta!} = \frac{\binom{n - m}{\zeta}}{\binom{n}{\zeta}}
$$

Then the probability of *not* failing is just:

$$
p(x = \zeta\text{, at least one success}) = 1 - \frac{\binom{n - m}{\zeta}}{\binom{n}{\zeta}}
$$

So you would have to set that equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ and solve for $\zeta$, which I don't think is exactly straightforward to do.  But here's an example: $n = 10, m = 5$:

$$
1 - \frac{5!(10 - \zeta)!}{(5 - \zeta)!10!}= \frac{1}{2} \\
1 - \frac{(10 - \zeta)!}{(5 - \zeta)!30,240} = \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{(10 - \zeta)!}{(5 - \zeta)!} = \frac{30,240}{2} = 15,120
$$

Now, I can't do anything but guess and test.  I would probably expect $\zeta$ to be around 2 or 3, so I'll start with $\zeta = 3$:

\begin{align*}
\zeta = 3:& \frac{7!}{2!} = 7*6*5*4*3 = 2,520 \leftarrow \text{ not big enough}\\
\zeta = 2:& \frac{8!}{3!} = 8*7*6*5*4 = 6,720 \leftarrow \text{ still not big enough} \\
\zeta = 1:& \frac{9!}{4!} = 9*8*7*6*5 = 15,120
\end{align*}

So that shouldn't have been surprising since each time you have a 50% chance of choosing one of the numbers...but it does sort of reinforce that this is probably correct.